# .pop function empties entire list

Tags: python

I am trying create a lattice structure that check to see if user input words can be formed in the lattice. The adjacency list goes through and checks all the nodes around it to see if the next user input letter matches. This particular example the list contains 4 elements, stored as a node class, surrounding the second input letter "O", however after attempting the pop the first letter just evaluated the whole list is cleared. Am I misunderstanding the use of the pop function?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Sry.png :before pop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4CrP.png :after pop

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, content):
    self.content = content


def getInput():
    data = str(input("Enter word to search for "))
    dataSplit = []

    #split input into letters
    for letter in data.upper():
        dataSplit.append(letter)

    return dataSplit


def createLattice():
    Node1 = Node("M")
    Node2 = Node("H")
    Node3 = Node("E")
    Node4 = Node("N")
    Node5 = Node("O")
    Node6 = Node("P")
    Node7 = Node("A")
    Node8 = Node("C")
    Node9 = Node("M")
    Node10 = Node("O")
    Node11 = Node("R")
    Node12 = Node("E")
    Node13 = Node("T")
    Node14 = Node("D")
    Node15 = Node("E")
    Node16 = Node("T")
    Node17 = Node("I")
    Node18 = Node("C")

    lattice = {Node1: [Node2, Node6, Node7],
               Node2: [Node1, Node3, Node5, Node8],
               Node3: [Node2, Node4, Node9],
               Node4: [Node3, Node5, Node10],
               Node5: [Node2, Node4, Node6, Node11],
               Node6: [Node5, Node1, Node12],
               Node7: [Node1, Node8, Node12, Node13],
               Node8: [Node2, Node7, Node9, Node12, Node14],
               Node9: [Node3, Node8, Node10, Node15],
               Node10: [Node4, Node9, Node11, Node16],
               Node11: [Node5, Node8, Node10, Node12, Node17],
               Node12: [Node6, Node7, Node11, Node18],
               Node13: [Node7, Node14, Node18],
               Node14: [Node8, Node13, Node15, Node17],
               Node15: [Node9, Node14, Node16],
               Node16: [Node10, Node15, Node17],
               Node17: [Node11, Node14, Node16, Node18],
               Node18: [Node12, Node13, Node17]}


    return lattice



def searchLattice(dataSplit, lattice):
    storeLetter = []
    adjacencyList = []
    firstLetter = dataSplit[0]

    for letter in dataSplit:
        for elem in adjacencyList:
            for node in elem:
                if node.content == letter:
                    storeLetter.append(letter)
                    adjacencyList.clear()
                    break
                elif node.content != letter:
                    adjacencyList.pop(0)
                    print(adjacencyList)

        for key in lattice:
            if letter == key.content:
                storeLetter.append(letter)
                adjacencyList.append(lattice[key])








def main():
    dataSplit = getInput()
    (lattice) = createLattice()
    searchLattice(dataSplit, lattice)

main()
```

Comment: Don't post photos of code. Copy, paste, and [format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your code in the body of the question. You can use the edit button to fix it.

Comment: You don't seem to have a list of 4 elements. You have list of 1 element, and that element is a list of 4 elements.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any usage of `pop` method in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the reason `pop` isn't behaving the way you expect it too is because you `adjacenyList` is a list of lists. When you are popping it looks something like this `[[<Node>, <Node>, <Node]]`. Popping the 0th element of that will just remove everything.

I am not entirely sure if this produces your desired final output, **but if you replace the line** `adjacencyList.pop(0)` **with** `adjacencyList[0].pop(0)` **you will prevent that error**.

It may also be prudent to think about whether you actually want `adjacencyList` to be a list of lists, or simply just a list of nodes. Hope this helps!